# How to encode and decode struct to NSData in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I have the following struct definition:

```swift
struct ThreadManager: Equatable {
  let fid: Int
  let date: NSDate
  let forumName: String
  let typeid: Int
  var page: Int
  var threadList: [Thread]
  var totalPageNumber: Int?
}
```

and the thread is :

```swift
  struct Thread: Equatable {
    let author: Author
    let replyCount: Int
    let readCount: Int
    let title: String
    let tid: Int
    let isTopThread: Bool
    var attributedStringDictionary: [String: NSAttributedString]
    var postDescripiontTimeString: String
    var hasRead: Bool
}
```

How can I encode a ThreadManager variable to NSData? I tried to used the following functions, but it does not worK.

```swift
func encode<T>(var value: T) -> NSData {
  return withUnsafePointer(&value) { p in
    NSData(bytes: p, length: sizeofValue(value))
  }
}

func decode<T>(data: NSData) -> T {
  let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(sizeof(T))
  data.getBytes(pointer, length: sizeof(T))

  return pointer.move()
}
```

I have ThreadManager items, and I want to store them into sqlite. So I need to convert them to NSData. I have a variable called threadManager, the number of items in its threadList is about 70. I run the code and set a breakpoint, and input encode(threadManager) in xcode console, it is only 73bytes. It is wrong. How can I encode and decode those struct to NSData.

Comment: You can't serialize class instances like `NSDate` and complex types like `String` just by using pointers. They have data which is stored by reference. You're going to have to go element by element to do the serialization. If you want to store the data as a binary blob then I would suggest considering using a property list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gwendal Roué : you are right, but I have to build another class according to each struct. I used the following method, it is ugly, but it works. Can you help me to improve it?

```
init(data: NSData) {
    let dictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! NSDictionary
    fid = (dictionary["fid"] as! NSNumber).integerValue
    date = dictionary["date"] as! NSDate
    forumName = dictionary["forumName"] as! String
    typeid = (dictionary["typeid"] as! NSNumber).integerValue
    page = (dictionary["page"] as! NSNumber).integerValue
    totalPageNumber = (dictionary["totalPageNumber"] as? NSNumber)?.integerValue
    let threadDataList = dictionary["threadDataList"] as! [NSData]
    threadList = threadDataList.map { Thread(data: $0) }
}
extension ThreadManager {
func encode() -> NSData {
    let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dictionary.setObject(NSNumber(integer: fid), forKey: "fid")
    dictionary.setObject(date, forKey: "date")
    dictionary.setObject(forumName, forKey: "forumName")
    dictionary.setObject(NSNumber(integer: typeid), forKey: "typeid")
    dictionary.setObject(NSNumber(integer: page), forKey: "page")
    if totalPageNumber != nil {
        dictionary.setObject(NSNumber(integer: totalPageNumber!), forKey: "totalPageNumber")
    }
    let threadDataList: [NSData] = threadList.map { $0.encode() }
    dictionary.setObject(threadDataList, forKey: "threadDataList")

    return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dictionary)
}
}
```

Comment: Using a dictionary is a neat idea that prevents creating a custom NSCoding class, you're right! If you want to improve it, I'd write `dic["date"] = date` instead of `dic.setObject(...)`. But it's bikeshedding: your code is already fine.

Answer (score 6):

If your database is to be read on any other platform (Android, the web, wherever), you'd better choosing a cross-platform format such as JSON, or spread your struct members in their dedicated columns in a database table.

If you only target iOS/OSX/tvOS/etc, I recommend NSCoder. It is efficient, and most importantly:

1. NSCoder is platform-independant, which means that your NSData coding and decoding is not dependent on the particular memory layout currently used by the platform. For example, you don't have to fear 32 / 64 bits compatibility.
2. NSCoder lets you change your type over time, while keeping the ability to import old versions of your struct.

The code below adds a `asData()` function to your struct, and an `init(data:)` initializer. Those two let you go back and forth from your struct to NSData.

```swift
import Foundation

struct MyStruct {
    let name: String
    let date: NSDate
}

extension MyStruct {
    init(data: NSData) {
        let coding = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! Coding
        name = coding.name as String
        date = coding.date
    }

    func asData() -> NSData {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(Coding(self))
    }

    class Coding: NSObject, NSCoding {
        let name: NSString
        let date: NSDate

        init(_ myStruct: MyStruct) {
            name = myStruct.name
            date = myStruct.date
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! NSString
            self.date = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("date") as! NSDate
        }

        func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
            aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
            aCoder.encodeObject(date, forKey: "date")
        }
    }
}

let encodedS = MyStruct(name: "foo", date: NSDate())
let data = encodedS.asData()
let decodedS =  MyStruct(data: data)
print(decodedS.name)
print(decodedS.date)
```

Comment: you are right, but I have to build another class according to each struct. I used the following method, it is ugly, but it works. Can you help me to improve it?